# Regular expression to match digits preceded by a dot

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have a string:

```
Product, Q.ty: 1, Price: 120.00
```

I want to select everything after the first comma up to the last two decimal digits (.00) - or, in other words, select the `Product`, which will be variable though; what is not variable is `, Q.t` and it is also known that the last two characters in the string will be two digits preceded by a dot `.` - However only the last one will be always `0`, the one preceding it could be anything `0-9`, but always a digit.

I've used this to match the string:

```
preg_replace('/' . preg_quote(', Q.t') . '.*?' . preg_quote('.00') . '/', '', $data );
```

the problem is that it fails when the last two digits are not 00 but something else like 50, 40, 30 etc. If I use the same regex with a single digit '0', it won't work either because it will catch the first 0 in a string like in my earlier example and will leave out the remaining 0.

How to adjust this expression to catch a group of digits preceded by a '.' dot?

*one further note: this preg_replace is inside a foreach loop; some data won't match at all the pattern I'm trying to pass; which is ok, so in those cases I can print the strings the way they are; but for the cases in the foreach where there's a match, I want to replace part of the string with nothing*

Thank you

Comment: As a slight hint, you can use `d` in regex to match a digit.

Comment: Could you possibly show other example strings, and let us know what else is static, like **Product,** and **Price:** I am assuming.

Comment: "Product" changes; ", Q.t" will stay there, the last two characters in string will always be digits and preceded by a dot '.'

Comment: I've edited my original question after your comment - thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 /([^,]*), Q\.ty: (\d*), Price: (\d*\.\d{2})/
```

By using `([^,]*),` it will use the comma in the string as the first delimiter. This will capture the beginning of the string up to the first comma, the second match will be quantity and the last match will be the price.

So your provided string:

```
 Product, Q.ty: 1, Price: 120.00
```

will return

```
$1 = Product
$2 = 1
$3 = 120.00
```

on a side note I don't know if that period after Q in Q.ty is intentional in your example or just a typo.

Comment: thanks, actually I don't need variables; the preg_replace in my original question is used in a foreach loop and some data won't match at all; I'm looking for something to replace the content of the preg_replace in my example, especially for the second preg_quote()

Comment: Here's a link so you can see that pattern in action in a preg replace.
http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/5tj-zx0

Those variables I listed are actually back references for the second argument of preg_replace. Which in my opinion is a little cleaner than your original pattern and allows you to reformat strings to however you desire with variable details. If you are adamant on keeping your expression.

Change
`'.*?' . preg_quote('.00'). '/',`  
to 
`'.*?\.\d0/',`

Answer (score 2):

Why not just

```
/(\d+\.\d{2})$/
```

which would capture any trailing "numbers" with a decimal place?

Comment: thanks, I need to get also everything after the first comma, not just the last number on the right; essentially I need to retain only the  "Product" label, in other words

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
(.+?), (Q\.ty: \d+, .+?\.\d{2})
```

This should capture everything from the first comma to the last two decimal digits into $2, with the product label being kept in $1

Comment: You're using a look behind. It doesn't actually "capture" the "Q\.ty:" part of the statement. It checks for its existence only.

Comment: Oops, I thought OP wanted the text after the comma in Q.ty. Answer edited.

Comment: That's cool. Just thought I would point that out for anyone not familiar with the look arounds.

Comment: doesn't work in my case - I'm looking for something to replace the second 'preg_quote()' in my original question, or something to replace the string inside preg_replace; I tried with the code in your example but didn't work

Answer (score 2):

I figured someone (there always is) would say "You can get the pieces with [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)." However it's not faster.

```
<?php

$string = "Product, Q.ty: 1, Price: 120.00";
$removals = array(",",":");


$stime = microtime();
    $nstring = str_replace($removals,'',$string);
    $parts = explode(" ",$nstring);

echo microtime()-$stime."secs\n";
    print_r($parts);

$pattern = "!^([A-Za-z]+),\s([A-Za-z.]+)\:\s([0-9]+),\s([A-Za-z]+):\s([0-9.]+)$!";

$ptime = microtime();
    $m = preg_match($pattern,$string,$matches);
echo microtime()-$ptime."secs\n";

print_r($matches);

?>
```

**Output**

```
4.0999999999958E-5secs
Array
(
    [0] => Product
    [1] => Q.ty
    [2] => 1
    [3] => Price
    [4] => 120.00
)
3.5000000000007E-5secs
Array
(
    [0] => Product, Q.ty: 1, Price: 120.00
    [1] => Product
    [2] => Q.ty
    [3] => 1
    [4] => Price
    [5] => 120.00
)
```

Using a more literal approach ,providing the `$string` doesn't deviate, does not improve performance of the preg_match function.

```
$pattern = "!^(Product), (Q\.ty): ([0-9]+), (Price): ([0-9.]+)$!";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a literal dot, you should scape it: \.